# StreamBuild: stream, calling a method that returns a Firestore Stream does not retrieve data until update

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, stream-builder

I'm hoping that someone can explain why there is different in behavior when explicitly calling *Firestore.instance.collection('data').snapshots()* vs calling a method that contain *Firestore.instance.collection('data').snapshots()* and returns a Stream.

Calling a method that contains *Firestore.instance.collection('data').snapshots()* only grabs the data snapshot after a change is made to the firestore data.

```
class GlobalAppModel extends Model{
......//other global data elements

  Stream getDataStreamSnapshots(){
    Firestore.instance.collection('data').snapshots();
  }
}
```

```
class DataDetailWidget2 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    dataStream = AppModel.of(context);
    ....
    body: Container(
        child: StreamBuilder(
          stream: Firestore.instance.collection('data').snapshots(), //This works great.
          //stream: dataStream.getDataStreamSnapshots(), //This does not grab a snapshot until firestore is updated.
          builder: (context, snapshot) { 
            .....
          }

    ....
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are just missing return keyword in your getDataStreamSnapshots method.

```
class GlobalAppModel extends Model{
......//other global data elements

  Stream getDataStreamSnapshots(){
    return Firestore.instance.collection('data').snapshots(); // return added
  }
}
```